# Exception upon retrieving DateTime field

Tags: c#, console-application, oledbdatareader

I am retrieving `DateTime` data from an access data base and want to assign it to an object as a string value.

```
OleDbDataReader dbRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dbRead.Read())
{
    product.DateReleased = dbRead["Date Released"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)dbRead["DATE"] : "No Date available";
    product.DatePublished = dbRead["Publish_Date"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)dbRead["Publish_Date"] : "No Date Available"; 
}
```

The property of the Product object is a string value and the value I am retrieving from the database is `DateTime`.

Trying to run the process gives me an `InvalidCastException` exception and I have a feeling it is because of a parsing issue.

Advice perhaps on where the problem is?

Regards

Comment: What is you date format in database

Comment: May be your `product.DateReleased` is DateTime and you try to assign it a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime` and `string` are different data types, and can't be casted to each other, like `int` and `float`. You need to parse `string` in order to retrieve `DateTime`. Try to use next code snippet to try to Parse `DateTime` with default format, provided in current culture.

```
OleDbDataReader dbRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 while (dbRead.Read())
 {
     product.DateReleased = dbRead["Date Released"] != DBNull.Value ? DateTime.Parse(dbRead["DATE"]) : null;
     product.DatePublished = dbRead["Publish_Date"] != DBNull.Value ? DateTime.Parse(dbRead["Publish_Date"]) : null; 
 }
```

Assuming `DatePublished`  and `DateReleased` is of type `DateTime?`. If you have specific date format, you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` method, which takes format as a parameter, for example

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dbRead["Date Released"], "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If `DatePublished`  and `DateReleased` are of type `string`, then you should call `ToString()` on a DateTime, to convert it to string, like:

```
product.DateReleased = dbRead["Date Released"] != DBNull.Value ? dbRead["DATE"].ToString() : "No Date available";
product.DatePublished = dbRead["Publish_Date"] != DBNull.Value ? dbRead["Publish_Date"].ToString() : "No Date Available";
```

If the underlying column in your database has a `DateTime` type, you can access `GetDateTime` method on the `OleDbDataReader` class, like

```
product.DateReleased = dbRead.GetDateTime("Date Released");
```